Colmap compute relative poses without database
I have the following outputs from COLMAP: points3D.bin, images.bin, cameras.bin, and project.ini. I need to convert these files to Bundler format, specifically generating EG.txt and gt_bundle.out.
I can export gt_bundle.out using COLMAP export commands. However, my main challenge is computing the relative poses needed for EG.txt from the COLMAP outputs. Since I do not have the database file, I am seeking any solutions or guidance on how to do this.
I would greatly appreciate any solution.
